# Existing open-source textual sentiment classifiers like Vader for Python?

Tags: python-2.7, open-source, classification, sentiment-analysis

I am currently using **Vader** sentiment classifier developed by Hutto and Gilbert to analyze tweets' sentiment on health topics, I am wondering what other available sentiment classifiers are out there free of use for blog/microblog or health settings, how are their performances compared to Vader, and are they Python friendly?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend reading the [VADER article](http://comp.social.gatech.edu/papers/icwsm14.vader.hutto.pdf). Section 4 (Results) compares it against several other methods.